# Reactjs setState arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

As per the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) we can have two ways for setState one with object syntax and other with function which they have shown as below

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}));
```

My understanding of **arrow function** syntax is like `() => {}` where flower brackets are followed after arrow `=>`, but as per the sample it is round braces instead of flower brackets

What is the difference between these syntax `()=>{}` and `()=>({})`.

Sample Code tried as per the docs which is working when `this.setStage(prevStage=>({}))` syntax is used in `handleClick` function, and if you change it to `this.setState(prevStage=>{})` it wont toggle the button value.

Below is the working code:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isToggleOn : true
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
          }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : "OFF"}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there was no Javascript error when () were removed !!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 2 main issues to consider here:

1. How [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) works?
2. What [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) expects when passing `function` as a parameter?

**Answers:**

1. Arrow functions can return a value implicitly or explicitly.
   When
   there is no function body (no curly brace `{}`) then you are
   returning implicitly:

   ```
   const x = () => 'we are returning a string here';
   ```

   When we use a function body, we need to use the `return` key word:

   ```
   const x = () => {
     return 'another string returned'
   };
   ```

   There is another option to return something without the `return` key
   word, you can wrap the curly brace with parentheses `()` and this
   will signal the engine that the curly brace are not a function body
   but an object, this is considered as creating an expression:

   ```
   const x = () => ({myKey: 'some string'});
   ```

   This is similar as we usually do with function expressions.
   Especially with IIFE (**I**mmediately **I**nvoked **F**unction
   **E**xpression) :

   ```
   (function() {
       //some logic...
   })();
   ```

   If we will not return anything, then the function will just return `undefined`.
2. As for `setState`, when you pass a function as a parameter, it
   expect that this function will return an object.
   When your function didn't return anything (as stated above) it actually
   returned `undefined`.
   JavaScript won't yield an error as this is not
   an error. its just a function that returns nothing (`undefined`).

Here is a running example of your code without the wrapping parentheses:

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: true
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { // we must return an object for setState
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
      } 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : "OFF"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Toggle />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comments

> I would expect Javascript to throw error when we return just key : value 
>   without enclosing parenthesis, i.e., () => {key:value} - which means
>   it is trying to return 'key:value' and not Object, and this should be
>   an JS error, but it did not throw any error. Please correct me if my
>   understanding is wrong

It is not returning a key value, it is a "void" function that returns `undefined`.
See this running snippet:

```js
const x = () => {myKey: 'myValue'};
const y = x();
console.log(y);
```

**Edit#2**
Followup to your other comments (which is basically kind of a whole different question in my opinion).

> let y = function() {'abc':1} - syntax error, let y = function(){abc:1}
>   and let y = function(){ return {'abc':1} } - no error, where first one
>   (syntax error) we are trying to assign 1 to string abc, which is same
>   as 3rd sample (no error), and 2nd example assigning 1 to abc - works
>   when there is no quotes. Please explain the difference of these 3
>   samples and why 1st one fails and not 2nd example

OK, this is getting interesting.

> where first one (syntax error) we are trying to assign 1 to string abc...

No we are not.
We are trying to create a [`label:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), but labels **can't** be strings!
Same as variables **can't** be strings - `var 'x' = 1`.

This is a valid syntax in JavaScript:

```
const y = function(){b:2};
```

What we are doing here is creating a [`label:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) named `a` and this label has an expression of `1` (we are not doing anything with this label.).

```js
const x = () => {a:1};
const y = function(){a:1};
```

This syntax is invalid:

```
const y = function() { 'a': 1 };
```

This is not valid because labels can't start with a string:

```js
const x = () => { 'a': 1 };
const y = function() { 'a': 1 };
```

And again, this is not a `key:value` pair, the curly brace are the function's **BODY**.

Comment: let x = () => { 'a' : 1 };

let y = () => ( { 'a' : 1 });

If we try only the above 2 expression in a file, I will be getting Javascript error for the first x assignment i.e, SyntaxError: Unexpected token : , but the sample code did not throw this syntax error when we dont have parenthesis around curly braces

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrow functions. you will get the same error if you do `let y = function(){'a':1}`. it won't throw an error if you will remove the quotes: `let y = function(){a:1}` but again, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: `let y = function() {'abc':1} ` - syntax error, `let y = function(){abc:1}`  and `let y = function(){ return {'abc':1} }` - no error, where first one (syntax error) we are trying to assign 1 to string abc, which is same as 3rd sample (no error), and 2nd example assigning 1 to abc - works when there is no quotes. Please explain the difference of these 3 samples and why 1st one fails and not 2nd example

Comment: @ChandreGowda i made another update to the answer, i hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I had a different question related to this, if we use the function syntax for setState, is state automatically passed in by react?

e.g `this.setState((state)=>({counter: state.counter+1}))`

Comment: @Altair21 yes, the most up do date state

Answer (score 11):

Later I referred [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and found details under Advanced Syntax section, that if you want to return objects implicitly then we need to enclose it within () , that answered my question.

> // Parenthesize the body of function to return an object literal expression:
>
> params => ({foo: bar})

Comment: The wrapping  `()` creates an expression

Comment: @Sagivb.g any idea why there was no Javascript error even when () was not added in sample code handleClick function where it was returning key value pair?

Comment: Arrow functions will return implicitly, but when you create a body for the function (using the `{}`) you will need to return explicitly `{ return {...} }`. If you need more info with link to the docs let me know and i will post a proper answer.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I would expect Javascript to throw error when we return just key : value without  enclosing parenthesis, i.e., () => {key:value} -  which means it is trying to return 'key:value' and not Object, and this should be an JS error, but it did not throw any error. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: its actually not returning a key value, its returning `undefined`. which is not an error in javascript. see my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer is

```
()=>({})
```

also it's equal to

```
()=> {
   return {}
 }
```

return an empty object,here parentheses around `{}` mean `return`. also you know we must pass object to `setState` so we insert any thing we want to state between `{}`

```
()=>({any thing you want to set to state})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only write () => {} this explicitly means that the function does more than return something.

For example:

```
const logAndReturn = (val) => {
  console.log(val)
  return val
}
```

But let's say you have a function that takes params and returns an object based on those params.

```
const createUser = (x) => { 
  prop: x
}
```

This will prompt an error cause this translates to:

```
function createUser(x) { 
  prop:x 
}
```

With parenthesis, you are still using the default return from the arrow function.

```
const createUser = (name, email) => ({})
function createUser(name, email) { return {} )
```

Comment: (x) => { prop : x } .. kind did not prompt error in the sample code i posted even without parenthesis surrounding flower brackets, that created some confusion.